# MopaBootstrapBundle using FontAwesome with mopabootstrap-3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just started a new project and I decided to use gulp to minimize and organize public libraries CSS and Javascript.

I have everything set up but I started to make a file .scss MopaBootstrapBundle including a library, namely this:

`@import 'web/bundles/mopabootstrap/sass/mopabootstrapbundle-fa';`

and run minify of gulp, it throws me an error.

> Error: web/bundles/mopabootstrap/sass/bootstrap-fontawesome.scss
>
> Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../bootstrap-sass/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables
>          Parent style sheet: web/bundles/mopabootstrap/sass/bootstrap-fontawesome.scss
>           on line 16 of web/bundles/mopabootstrap/sass/bootstrap-fontawesome.scss

I was checking the directory and the folder vendor isn't exists.

[image]

It just works if i add 3.2 version of mopa:

```
@import 'web/bundles/mopabootstrap/sass/mopabootstrapbundle-3.2';
```

Then how can i add the font awesome support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question but perhaps the answer should be provided. Currently MopaBootstrapBundle doesnt offer working version of sass file that allows including font-awesome. Below I attach working code that you must include by yourself.

```
@import "../../../../../vendor/mopa/bootstrap-bundle/Mopa/Bundle/BootstrapBundle/Resources/public/sass/font-awesome/font-awesome.scss";
```